# What are the main pros / cons for smart contract development on EOS vs Ethereum smart contracts?

Tags: smart-contract, ethereum

What are the pros and cons when doing smart contract development when coming from Ethereum? How does one differ in strength and weakness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EOS smart contracts are built on the top of C++. This gives a huge boost in the productivity, as C++ has existing toolchains available (compiler, debugger, static analysers, etc.). EOS smart contracts are also more powerful in the sense, they can be bigger, execute delayed actions and so fort.

EOS smart contracts are built on the top of C++. This is also a downside, because C++ is not a safe language. Albeit having spotty history, Solidity language development tries to push the language toward being safer so that more and more bugs are caught int the compile phase.

Please note that EOS smart contracts, in theory, can be written in any language that compiles down to WASM. However, currently C++ is the only officially supported language.